# Launch error while using Tkinter Gui on Mac Os

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am getting the following error while trying to run a Tkinter GUI on my Mac
I am trying to create a trading bot and using Tkinter GUI to visualise it and give some commands:
How can it be resolved?

```
  matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
2021-04-13 00:48:27.816 Python[6471:70564] -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb9756bef10
2021-04-13 00:48:27.817 Python[6471:70564] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb9756bef10'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2049e6af __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff201d63c9 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20520c85 -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2040607d ___forwarding___ + 1467
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20405a38 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Tk                                  0x00007fff6ff85bae TkpInit + 826
    6   Tk                                  0x00007fff6ff056a8 Tk_Init + 1698
    7   _tkinter.so                         0x000000010e8dabc4 Tcl_AppInit + 84
    8   _tkinter.so                         0x000000010e8da59a init_tkinter + 20598
    9   Python                              0x000000010e5e978b PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19816
    10  Python                              0x000000010e5e4410 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 536
    11  Python                              0x000000010e58b29c PyFunction_SetClosure + 772
    12  Python                              0x000000010e56d861 PyObject_Call + 97
    13  Python                              0x000000010e5780e1 PyMethod_New + 1169
    14  Python                              0x000000010e56d861 PyObject_Call + 97
    15  Python                              0x000000010e5ee26f PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 159
    16  Python                              0x000000010e57641a PyInstance_New + 123
    17  Python                              0x000000010e56d861 PyObject_Call + 97
    18  Python                              0x000000010e5e9775 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19794
    19  Python                              0x000000010e5ee923 _PyEval_SliceIndexNotNone + 384
    20  Python                              0x000000010e5e96d5 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19634
    21  Python                              0x000000010e5e4410 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 536
    22  Python                              0x000000010e5e41f2 PyEval_EvalCode + 32
    23  Python                              0x000000010e606ca9 PyParser_ASTFromFile + 279
    24  Python                              0x000000010e606d50 PyRun_FileExFlags + 130
    25  Python                              0x000000010e6068d7 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 703
    26  Python                              0x000000010e61845b Py_Main + 3203
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff20347621 start + 1
    28  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code that caused the problem (please make sure it's minimalistic)? Did you use threading with tkinter?

Comment: @TheLizzard Pls have a look here : https://ideone.com/tzFX3G

Comment: That is too much code. Try removing the unnecessary pieces to make it easier to debug.

Comment: @TheLizzard Have made the required changes to make it easier

Comment: You know that you can combine all of those `.configure(...)`s into 1? So instead of writing `<>.configure(...)` and `<>.configure(...)` you can just use `<>.configure(..., ...)`.

Comment: @TheLizzard okay. Also, can you please look into what is causing the issue/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231055/discussion-between-slayer1996-and-thelizzard).

Comment: was this resolved?